# Hilbert space and relation between two inner products.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

i'm trying to do an exercise and i'm stuck.

It goes as follows,

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with his inner product $ \langle \cdot ,  \cdot\rangle $. Let $\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$ an other inner product over $H$. We suppose that $(x,y) \rightarrow \langle x,y \rangle_1$ is continuous over $H \times H$.

> Show that there exists a unique linear continuous map $u$ from $H$ to $H$ such that for every $x,y \in H$, $\langle x,y\rangle_1=\langle u(x),y\rangle $

I think i have to use the Riez represenation theorem but i think i don't really understand what is the relationship between the two inner products.

Thank you !

Comment: For every $y$ the mapping $x\mapsto \langle x,y\rangle_1$ is continuous and linear. Now you can apply the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: More generally, if $(\cdot\mid\cdot)$ is a sesquilinear form such that there is $M \ge 0$ such that $|(x\mid y)| \le M\|x\|\|y\|$ for all $x,y \in H$, then there exists a (necessarily unique) $u \in B(H)$ such that $(x\mid y) = \langle u(x), y\rangle$ for all $x,y \in H$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace The exercise aimed at proving that. The proof of this more general fact goes along the same lines, except that $u$ is injective and positive  in the case of the inner product.

Comment: Riesz theorem implies that $\langle x,y\rangle _1=\langle x, u(y)\rangle $ for a unique element $u(y)\in \mathcal{H}.$ Now you should prove that the mapping $y\mapsto u(y)$ is linear and bounded.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes I know, which is why I said "More generally" (you can immediately prove the more general statement with the same work).